# {{ front_page }} doesn't work in partial

Tags: theming, 8

I have a partial, partials/header.html.twig, I am calling on one of my sub pages with this code.

```
{% include directory ~ '/partials/header.html.twig' %}
```

Whenever I use `{{ front_page }}` inside the partial to link back to the front page, it doesn't work, but it works on everything else. I have been searching for an answer all morning but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: In which twig template is the `{% include ... %}`?

Comment: @4k4 The `{% include ... %}` is located in `page--taxonamy--term--%.html.twig`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<a href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Some Title'|t }}" rel="home" class="some-class">
     Some Text
    </a>
```